# How to Validate Facebook account without phone number or creditcard

Tags: facebook, validation, facebook-graph-api

I am in a country where facebook is forbidden and I am seeking to use the facebook api's and the SDK. To do so I need to validate the account via the code sent by sms or a credit card validation. The credit card validation is not an option for me and the SMS I receive delivers 2 to 3 hours late and when I enter the six code validation digit I receive an error message saying its the wrong code. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and is there a way around this to use the facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not ideal but you could download the SDK's from Github. I found the PHP SDK for you [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk). The JS SDK is outdated. The Android SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) should be the iOS SDK. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for because it's just the APIs itself. More explanation and exampled can be found on developers.facebook.com but as you stated that FB is forbidden in your country, I don't know if you'll be able to reach it.

Hope my answer helped you anyways. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, I can actually reach Facebook with a vpn connection, but from what I understand to use the Facebook API's I have to have a Key and to do so I need a validated facebook account. Isn't that the case?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure when Facebook marks your account as "validated", but it's very likely that you have to be validated in order to create an app to get your key & secret.